# Detect all words belonging to a different language

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

I have a long technical text in Spanish. There a many words in English inside the text, because the terms are not normally translated. I want to make all of them cursive, as it's mandated by Spanish grammar.

The first step is therefore locating them. Is there a way of finding all words in a text which are part of the English dictionary? Moreover, some words will be common to both languages and appear often in the text (for example, "a"), so the method would need a way of me ignoring occurrences of certain words.

Unfortunately, not all of them are marked as errors in Spanish, either because the word is accepted in Spanish or because I added it to the local dictionary so that it would not be counted as a spelling mistake, so I cannot locate all of them via "Spell checking".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is something you can do.  A lot depends on the structure and meta data on your document so you may have phenomenal or mediocre results.

Then there's the fact that I don't frequently use this feature, so I may not be aware of ways to improve performance.

1. Open the advanced find window  (it's on the right side of the ribbon on the home tab)
2. Click the format button (Bottom left corner,)
3. Click language

   - Select you language of choice
   - click ok
4. In the advanced find window, check the box "use wildcard"

   - And use a single asterisk as your search terms  (shift 8 = *)
   - Give that a shot
     -You may have immediate success but don't give up if it didn't work
5. click on language in the review tab of the ribbon

   - click language preferences
   - confirm your desired language is installed.
   - Click ok
6. Click on language in the ribbon again

   - Click set proofing language
   - Select the opposite of whatever if active
   - Ensure "detect language automatically" is enabled
   - Click ok
7. Go back to the advanced find window

   - make sure your options have reverted
   - try finding again

> **"Moreover, some words will be common to both languages and appear often in the text (for example, "a"), so the method would need a way of me ignoring occurrences of certain words."**

This is going to be a problem.  Especially with languages that share long intermingled histories.  There are some strategies you can employ to work through it - and one is destructive, so **make sure you're working from a copy and not the original!**

- You may have luck translating out of Spanglish into a third, more distant language.  That should break  some commonalities but it may not be enough to really get you going.
- remove all of the words from the language you don't want to find.  If you're looking for English, remove all the Spanish works.  This will declutter your document and help you find patterns that you may have otherwise missed.
- read this article on pattern matching with wildcards
  https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.pcworld.com/article/3060753/word-pro-tips-use-wildcards-for-faster-more-accurate-search-and-replace-results.amp.html

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for this, it looks promising! However, it seems to find individual characters in a couple of words in English (it will match "w", "h", "i", "l", "e" in "while", for example) and then completely ignore all the rest of the document. I'll keep digging!

Comment: @user2891463 I added a couple more tips to the bottom of the post that I think will help you   the link in particular will help with the single character words.

Comment: Hmmm... Looks like the issue is that "Format/Language" in the advanced search will only look in paragraphs marked as English, while these words are inserted in paragraphs in Spanish. I can look for full words with "<*>", but there is no way of looking for English words in Spanish paragraphs that I've found.

Comment: @User2891462 Try changing the proofing language to Spanish.